# Math.max Function in Javascript

Tags: javascript, max

I have this simple issue that I can't figure out trying to find out the max from a string, yes it is a string, converting to a float. According to JS it can take an array... but everytime I try to find the max it is just printing the first value. In this case 13... not sure why? The expected result is 30.

Please help. Thanks!

```
function myFunction() {
    var str = "13, 24, 30, 4";//30
    var res = str.split(",");

    var max =    Math.max(parseFloat(res));

    document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = res+ " " + max;//test

    }
```

Comment: `res` is an array. `parseFloat` takes a string. `Math.max` does not take an array, but multiple arguments.

Comment: Take a look at Bergi's answer. Pay special attention to how he's using the "apply" on the Math.max function.

Comment: I will try to test this out. I have actually found a solution myself a couple of hours later. It does help to find some expert or experienced opinions. Thanks a bunch!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`res` is an array. `parseFloat` takes a string. `Math.max` does not take an array, but multiple arguments. Notice that you don't even need `parseFloat`, as `Math.max` casts its arguments to numbers anyway. So you have to use [`apply`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/apply) to get the array into `Math.max`:

```
var str = "13, 24, 30, 4";
var max = Math.max.apply(Math, str.split(", "));

document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = "max("+res+") = "+max;
```

Comment: Oh sorry Bergi! Thanks! I didn't know that's how to do it in here such a noob.